# Embedding conditional statements in relative and complement clauses

Tags: cross-linguistic, frequency

I happened to run across the following sentence [on ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20304/how-to-parse-these-crazy-sentences/20331#20331):

> Anyone who feels that if so many more students whom we haven't actually admitted are sitting in on the course than ones we have that the room had to be changed, then probably auditors will have to be excluded, is likely to agree that the curriculum needs revision.

A significant part of the complexity of this sentence arise from the inclusion of the conditional statement "if so many more students... then probably auditors will have to be excluded" within a complement clause "that if so... excluded" (which is itself embedded in a relative clause "who feels that... excluded".

It occurred to me that the possibility of embedding a conditional within a complement or relative clause is probably cross-linguistically rare.

Comment: Just to be clear: your question is whether this is indeed rare? I would expect not. There are restrictions on sentence types, for example: imperatives can only be embedded in few languages, usually under strong restrictions. But gut feeling tells me that since a conditional is essentially just an assertion, by the principle of recursion it should be possible to embed it like simple clauses. Like all recursion this is always *practically* limited since the overall complexity cannot be too high.

Comment: Especially in complement clauses it would be odd if conditionals weren't allowed. Then how are you going to express conditionals in indirect speech, like *John said that he would leave if Mary came*?

Comment: @Keelan I suppose it could be something like "According to John, he would leave if Mary came."

Comment: With a light verb like *say* you can do that, but not when you use a verb with more lexical content (*John shouted that ...*) or add an adverb (*John supposedly said that ...*).